# ContentResolver.insert() returns null, no exceptions

Tags: android, sqlite

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("username", username);
values.put("system", "NULL");
values.put("local_password", "NULL");
Uri test = getContentResolver().insert(DataProvider.PROFILES_URI, values);
```

This always returns null for test. I get no exceptions in logcat. Shouldn't it be a URL? The row is inserted into the database, as it is retrieved later in other places.

Comment: it depends on DataProvider implementation ... who did this implementation ?

Comment: I did, the code is available if need be. DataProvider.PROFILES_URI is defined as `public static final Uri PROFILES_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.nuance.dmmr.marshall.dataprovider/profiles");` and as I said, the row is being inserted.

Comment: so ...  your code  DataProvide looks like this `@Override
 public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) { /* ...insert to db goes here... */ return null;}` and it acts as it should. Where is your problem then?

Comment: Heh, the problem is between my ears. Of course if I override the super implementation **I** have to return what I want. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. If ye want to throw this up as an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Android's `ContentResolver` does not support remote exceptions yet. In my case, I had to remove all filters in `LogCat` (selected Verbose and No Filters) to be able to see the exception that was being logged.